# Where do I have to put the dispose()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dispose, streamreader, streamwriter

simple question cause I'm too dumb atm. I'm using streamreader and writer and it gives me the exception that the file is used by another process already. I know I have to set a `.dispose()` somewhere. But I really don't know where. I'm too blind.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btn_Geht_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sPath = @"C:\VSTO\Projects\Zeiterfassung\Zeiterfassung\obj\Debug\Zeiten.txt";
    cZeile Geht = new cZeile();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sPath))
    {
        Geht = cZeiterfassung.GetZeileObjectFromZeileString(sr.ReadLine(), ";");

        Geht.Geht = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        Geht.dtGeht = DateTime.Now;
        sr.Dispose();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPath))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(sPath, string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmm};{1};{2:dd.MM.yyyy};{3:hh:mm};{4:hh:mm}", Geht.ID, Geht.User, Geht.Datum, Geht.Kommt, Geht.Geht));
        }
    }
```

I get the error here:

`File.WriteAllText(sPath, string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmm};{1};{2:dd.MM.yyyy};{3:hh:mm};{4:hh:mm}", Geht.ID, Geht.User, Geht.Datum, Geht.Kommt, Geht.Geht));`

the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: Remove `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPath))`.

Comment: `Dispose()` inside the `using` is "a bit" strange. Do the `File.WriteAllText` outside of the first `using` which already disposes of `sr`. Then you don't need to explicitly Dispose of it.

Answer (score 6):

You should remove:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPath))
```

since you are not actually using `sw` (and it is locking the file).

So:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPath))
{
    File.WriteAllText(sPath, string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmm};{1};{2:dd.MM.yyyy};{3:hh:mm};{4:hh:mm}", Geht.ID, Geht.User, Geht.Datum, Geht.Kommt, Geht.Geht));
}
```

will become:

```
File.WriteAllText(sPath, string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmm};{1};{2:dd.MM.yyyy};{3:hh:mm};{4:hh:mm}", Geht.ID, Geht.User, Geht.Datum, Geht.Kommt, Geht.Geht));
```

In short, your `sw` is locking the file - making `File.WriteAllText` not able to write to it.

The entire code block could thus be:

```
protected void btn_Geht_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sPath = @"C:\VSTO\Projects\Zeiterfassung\Zeiterfassung\obj\Debug\Zeiten.txt";
    cZeile Geht = null; // no point newing up an object since you are about to assign to it below

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sPath))
    {
        Geht = cZeiterfassung.GetZeileObjectFromZeileString(sr.ReadLine(), ";");

        Geht.Geht = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        Geht.dtGeht = DateTime.Now;
    }

    File.WriteAllText(sPath, string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmm};{1};{2:dd.MM.yyyy};{3:hh:mm};{4:hh:mm}", Geht.ID, Geht.User, Geht.Datum, Geht.Kommt, Geht.Geht));
}
```

*Note that the `using` will call `Dispose` on `sr` automatically.*